define Nix Flake package which builds all other Flake packages
Based on this thread: https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/7165
I have a Flake with packages a, b and c. I want to define the default package so that all three are built; so nix build tests all three.

Based on this comment https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/7165#issuecomment-1309220847
and https://www.tweag.io/blog/2022-09-22-rust-nix/
Define a package all:
packages.all = pkgs.symlinkJoin {
  name = "all";
  paths = [ packages.a packages.b packages.c ];
};
default = packages.all;

